# Conflict when linking angularjs modules with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to port an existing angularjs app to ionic. The ionic project was created with;

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

Then, I combined the links from my angularjs app and ionic app together.

```
<!--ionic links-->
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="  stylesheet">
  -->
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <!--<div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>-->
</head>
<body>

<script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<script src="../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>

<script src="../../bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers-func.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

I launched Chrome browser and load the URL http://127.0.0.1/ionicapp/www/
The error encountered is

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $$forceReflowProvider <- $$forceReflow <- $$animateQueue <- $animate
>   <- $compile <- $$animateQueue
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24forceReflowProvid…eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

This error comes from `ionic.bundle.js: 8900`

I suspect the problem lies with some conflicts in the links. `ionic.bundle.js` may already contains some angularjs code. If yes, how should the links conflict be reconciled?

Answer (score 2):

The hint can be found in this documentation

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html

> Ionic comes with ngAnimate and ngSanitize bundled in, but to use other
>   Angular modules you’ll need to include them from the lib/js/angular
>   directory.

`ionic.bundle.js` already comes bundled with animate module. So, your html file creates conflict when you link in the angularjs animate module.

In your html file, comment away the following lines. This should be enough to solve your problem.

```
<!--<script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="../../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>-->
```

Please note that your other js modules need to be placed in `lib/js`. They can be placed in sub-folders in `lib/js`. Otherwise, it will work well when testing on desktop browser but fail to work on the smartphone.